# Bonding of my Broken Dining table glass

Tags: home

My dining table glass is broken at a particular area, that has become powder at that one point...is there any way to bond those powdered glass...I jst want to get rid of the powder coming from the table...i want to bond that powdered glass
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgErN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with windshield repair kit (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjuWqBzO7qY), but it seems that the glass is too damaged to be fixed easily.

Windshield repair kit should fill the center hole and fix the powdered glass part.

Comment: Good, thanks for the video...But in my case, the crack area is round 80mm in dia...Is there any tool kit available in the market ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had reasonable success for damage of that kind using superglue (cyanoacrylate). If you can find one that is thinner/more fluid it will flow into the cracks better. For cracked glass you don't need to separate it, just apply the superglue along the top of the crack and it will creep into it via capillary action. Model (airplane etc) shops are a good source of cyanoacrylate in various consistencies/fluidities

The glue is reasonably optically clear too, so diminishes the appearance of the crack, but it isn't dedicatedly optically clear. Such glue also exists, referred to as LOCA and normally used to glue things like mobile phone screen glass to the actual phone LCD so widely available from large online shopping destinations as well as local phone repair stores. Sets using uv light so  don't leave it out in the sun before you want to use it!

Comment: This seems to be we can use only for mobile dispalys where as my glass thickness is around 12mm & at a dia of 80mm, anymore suggestions?

Comment: You said you wanted a solution that stops the powdered glass from going everywhere, not something that will bond the table back to full strength. Cyanoacrylate will definitely stop the powdered glass migrating